# the "global" command is not available (vscode)

Tags: visual-studio-code

I keep getting

> the "global" command is not available. Make sure it is on PATH

(in a top bar in Visual Studio code)
when pressing ctrl in vs code. Where does this come from and how do I prevent it from showing?

Comment: Likely from an extension.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. this turned out to come from the "Pascal" highlighter, which executes a "global" command.

Comment: The Pascal highlighter calls a command called gnu "Global" in the background it turns out: https://github.com/alefragnani/vscode-language-pascal/search?utf8=✓&q=global&type=

Comment: @LukasSalich to fix it you just need to install "global". On fedora: `sudo dnf install global`

Comment: I am getting this on Windows 10 upon startup.

Answer (score 0):

Directions to install global on macOS: https://macappstore.org/global/